# Write MSIL interpreter - how to describe operational semantics?

Tags: interpreter, cil

I want to write MSIL interpreter using Mono Cecil to parsing but interpretation I want to do it yourself. I've seen a lot of examples but mostly for expression only. How to describe operational semantics for MSIL? I dont know how to start with this task so any advice will be valuable.

Comment: Did you read the specification?

Comment: Take a look at http://www.kframework.org/index.php/Main_Page and at the languages already defined this way. IL should be pretty easy to specify, comparing to C or Verilog.

Answer (score 2):

Simplifying a lot, you need stack frames for the call stack that each contain the local variables and the local stack as necessary for each method.
This can also be implemented in a flat stack, in which case you'd just have to keep track of the return pointers and current offset for variable-IO.
The [OpCodes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.opcodes%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) documentation should give you a good overview over how CIL code interacts with that structure.

Interpreting complete executables is quite a bit more involved due to special cases - you'd have to reimplement part of the runtime (and framework, for methods that need cooperation from the runtime) and [the relevant specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-335.pdf) spans a few hundred pages.

You could also have a look at the [Mono source code](http://www.mono-project.com/SourceCodeRepository), but that is most likely a lot more involved than what you want to do due to running natively.